# Publish to iCloud from Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspicam

I'd like to use the Rasp Pi Camera to take a picture of my plant and then publish to my iCloud account.

Q: What is the best way to publish to iCloud from a Raspberry Pi?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Snap store](https://snapcraft.io/icloud-for-linux) offers a version of iCloud for Raspbian that you could use.

Comment: on `sudo apt install core` I get:  error: snap "core" is not available on stable for this architecture (armel) but exists on other
       architectures (amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x).... so i guess it won't work at least on the rasp pi build i have.  The other challenge is it is not clear how to cli or programmatically put files into the icloud folder...hmm.. thank you.

Comment: @user1255603 `armel`? what model Pi, OS (including version) do you run on?

Answer (score 0):

The right command will be

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install core
```

You have to install `snapd` first.